# How to fix btn width in bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm just try to make sure that no matter the length of the text inside my tables, the `.btn` should make both `text fit` and `Long event text that absolutely does not fit(shown on hover)` the same `width` without affecting any other text outside that day.  For example, not because `Long event text that absolutely does not fit(shown on hover)` has length whatever in day 2, it doesn't mean that day 1 or day 5 should `overflow`.

NOTE: When I mentioned `.btn width` I am talking about the colors.  Colors should wrap the text.  without increasing the width from the others text, but only the one inside that day.

```css
.inside-date, .td-top-text {
    text-align: right;
    
}
.inside-event {
    text-align: left;
    
}
.inside-event.btn {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    color: black;
}
td.td-top-text {
    width:14.28571428571429%; /* 100% divided by 7 */
    position:relative;
}
td.td-top-text:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    margin-top:100%;
    position: relative;
}
td.td-top-text .inside {
    position:absolute;
    top:2px;
    bottom:2px;
    left:2px;
    right:2px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class=" td-top-text"></td>
            <td class=" td-top-text"></td>
            <td class=" td-top-text"></td>
            <td class=" td-top-text"></td>
            <td class=" td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">
                    <div class="inside-date">1</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-primary" title="Event text 1(shown on hover)">Event text 1</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-warning" title="Event text 2(shown on hover)">Event text 2</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-success" title="Event text 3(shown on hover)">Event text 3</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-primary" title="Event text 4(shown on hover)">Event text 4</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-warning" title="Event text 5(shown on hover)">Event text 5</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-success" title="Event text 6(shown on hover)">Event text 6</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-primary" title="Event text 7(shown on hover)">Event text 7</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-warning" title="Event text 8(shown on hover)">Event text 8</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-success" title="Event text 9(shown on hover)">Event text 9</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class=" td-top-text">
              <div class="inside">
                <div class="inside-date">2</div>
                <div class="inside-event btn btn-primary" title="Text fits(shown on hover)">Text fits</div>
                <div class="inside-event btn btn-warning btn-block" title="Long event text that absolutely does not fit(shown on hover)">Long event text that absolutely does not fit</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class=" td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">3</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">4</div>
            </td>
            <td class="td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">5</div>
            </td>
            <td class="td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">6</div>
            </td>
            <td class="td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">7</div>
            </td>
            <td class="td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">8</div>
            </td>
            <td class="td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">9</div>
            </td>
            <td class="td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">10</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**

So this is how it should look like but without affecting the side of the `box` where the test is in.

[image]

In this picture the table is affected by the side of the text.

**Edit:**

If I change my:

```
.inside-event.btn {
   text-align: left;
 padding: 0px;
 line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

**To**

```
.inside-event.btn {
width: auto;
min-width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
}
```

**I still getting this:**

[image]

The color doesn't cover the text.

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: Should the text wrap to the next line if it is too long?

Comment: @TimLewis the text should be in that square.  I just want to increase the `width color`

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Hi there, I'm just try to increase the width of anything inside my `long text` without affecting others day's text

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith How can I improve this question? if its not clear enough

Comment: @TimLewis Do you understand the question now? or feel free to edit and improve my question...

Comment: what browser are you using?... seems fine in chrome

Comment: @ArielMaduro I don't care about the bounty, but I'd like to know if there's something wrong with my solution.

Comment: @zer00ne Hi there, yes, two things, the date (number 2) is not moving to the right and is affecting my other events.  check this link: http://i66.tinypic.com/24me1pd.png

Comment: I see, so that little number should hug the right border, ok.

Comment: But also the other events

Comment: @zer00ne i really like your answer coz i dont have to worry about a new class, but its affecting the all table =/

Comment: @ArielMaduro I see the problem, when I affect the `.inside-date` and I adjust accordingly, the other boxes markup is different than the boxes with content. So when a box has content, the date is wrapped in a div, but if the box is empty, the date is unwrapped and is considered the text node of `.inside`. Must be a Bootstrap thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a new answer, this one, answer your question.

I use a new `<div class="inside-content">` with `display:table; width:100%` and inside events are in display:block and all works :)

```css
.inside-date, .td-top-text {
    text-align: right;
    
}

.inside-content {
    display:table;
    min-width:100%;
 }
.inside-event {
    text-align: left;
    
}
.inside-event.btn {
    text-align: left;
    display:block;
    width:auto;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    color: black;
}
td.td-top-text {
    width:14.28571428571429%; /* 100% divided by 7 */
    position:relative;
}
td.td-top-text:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    margin-top:100%;
    position: relative;
}
td.td-top-text .inside {
    position:absolute;
    top:2px;
    bottom:2px;
    left:2px;
    right:2px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Sun</th>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class=" td-top-text"></td>
        <td class=" td-top-text"></td>
        <td class=" td-top-text"></td>
        <td class=" td-top-text"></td>
        <td class=" td-top-text">
            <div class="inside">
                <div class="inside-content">
                    <div class="inside-date">1</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-primary" title="Event text 1(shown on hover)">Event text 1</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-warning" title="Event text 2(shown on hover)">Event text 2</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-success" title="Event text 3(shown on hover)">Event text 3</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-primary" title="Event text 4(shown on hover)">Event text 4</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-warning" title="Event text 5(shown on hover)">Event text 5</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-success" title="Event text 6(shown on hover)">Event text 6</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-primary" title="Event text 7(shown on hover)">Event text 7</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-warning" title="Event text 8(shown on hover)">Event text 8</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-success" title="Event text 9(shown on hover)">Event text 9</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class=" td-top-text">
            <div class="inside">
              <div class="inside-content">
                <div class="inside-date">2</div>
                <div class="inside-event btn btn-primary" title="Text fits(shown on hover)">Text fits</div>
                <div class="inside-event btn btn-warning btn-block" title="Long event text that absolutely does not fit(shown on hover)">Long event text that absolutely does not fit</div>
            </div>
</div>
        </td>
        <td class=" td-top-text">
            <div class="inside">3</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td-top-text">
            <div class="inside">4</div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-top-text">
            <div class="inside">5</div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-top-text">
            <div class="inside">6</div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-top-text">
            <div class="inside">7</div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-top-text">
            <div class="inside">8</div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-top-text">
            <div class="inside">9</div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-top-text">
            <div class="inside">10</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! this work perfectly.  You will get the 50 reputation after 23 hours! rules from SO

Comment: Hey, is there a way to fix the height to 100% no matter if that square get bigger so I wouldn't need the overflow-y?

Comment: I tried to add `min-height: 100%;` under `min-width: 100%;` but it didn't work

Comment: min-height:100% doesn't work unless you have an height on the parent.
Where do you want to add min-height:100% ? Another warning about your code, position:relative doesn't work on Table, tr, td (every element with display:table-*), Test under firefox you will be surprised.

Comment: wow how can I fix the position?  I am using firefox 42.0 and it looks fine.  Also, what I am trying to do with the height is delete the scroll Y and just show the list vertically, no matter the size of the Y

Comment: I'm looking for a solution

Comment: This is what I am trying to do http://postimg.org/image/nysbrlzxt/ but the height should be 100%

Comment: Gotttt itt...I change the position and it works fine in all browsers now thankss

Comment: Can you give us your solution ? I was sleeping (it was night for me)

Comment: Hey I just switch the `positions: td.td-top-text:before { position: relative;}
td.td-top-text .inside {position:absolute;}` to `{ position: absolute;}
td.td-top-text .inside {position:relative;}`